# Comparing a UITouch location to UIImageView rectangle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitouch

I have the following code to determine if a touch is within an image view in my table cell. However, it doesn't work. I compared the two with CGRectContainsPoint however, it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event    
{
     // Declare the touch and get it's location

     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

     CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

     if (CGRectContainsPoint(myImageView.frame, touchLocation))
     {
        NSLog(@"Tapped image view");
     }    
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 26):

> However, it doesn't work.

Please be more specific.

> ```
>  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
> ```

Why not examine *every* touch, and not simply a random* pick of them?

*[The documentation for `anyObject`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSet/anyObject) says that you are not guaranteed which one it will give you. You are not even guaranteed that it will be random; it could be the same object every time. Murphy's Law says that, whether it is random or not, it will be the wrong one.

> ```
>  CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
>  if (CGRectContainsPoint(myImageView.frame, touchLocation))
> ```

Your `frame` is in your superview's co-ordinate system; `[touch locationInView:self]` returns the touch point in *your* co-ordinate system. You want to test within `bounds`, which is in your co-ordinate system. [The documentation explains the difference.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW6)

Comment: expanding: `CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self]; if (CGRectContainsPoint(myImageView.frame, touchLocation))` only works if `myImageView` is a direct subview of `self`

Comment: expanding on Joao's comment, you can get a subview's frame relative to the superview (or any view) with `CGRect frameRelativeToView = [myImageView convertRect:myImageView.bounds toView:self]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to be calling [touch locationInView:myImageView] to get the point in the image views coordinate system.  Then do your check to see if it's within the frame.

Answer (score 1):

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
if ([touch view]==view) {
view.center=location;
}
```

write it in the touch moved event. thanx

Answer (score 0):

Remember that when you're asking a touch for locationInView:, you're getting out a point relative to that view's frame. So, assuming the code snippet you gave was contained in a subclass of UIViewController you should be asking for

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
```

Which will give you a point relative to your view. The reason you want a point relative to your current view is because the frame of your image view is also relative to its parent view - the same view. So now it should work.

```
 if (CGRectContainsPoint(myImageView.frame, touchLocation)) {
    NSLog(@"Tapped image view");
 }
```